# finding a li with specific title and removing the rest li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have a list in which i need to select an element (according to title attr of `<a>` inside `<li>`) on page load and remove rest of list elements except the selected one.

Using this:

```
$("#div").find("a[title='Previous Page']").not(this).remove();
```

Its not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymhrF/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#custom_pagination").find("a").not('[title="umm"]').parent('li').remove();
```

If you wanted to keep it as a single line of code.

Answer (score 1):

The logic I would follow is:

- Take all the list elements (`li`)
- Select those that do not have a child `a` that has the specified title (this is very easy using the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method which I really recommend getting familiar with)
- Remove the selected one

One way you could accomplish this plan is:

```
$('#list li')
    .filter(function () {
        return !$(this).has('a[title="Previous Page"]').length;
    })
    .remove();
```

You could write the filtering function in a lot of ways (use `find()` instead of `has()` or use some kind of combined selectors), but I really think you should use `filter()`. It makes your code more readable and describes quite well what is happening actually.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NxaNF/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li")
    .each(function(){
        if( $(this).find("a").is("[title='yourTitle']") ){
            $(this)
                .siblings()
                .remove();
        }
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/PAHVq/).

Or you could do it a bit more simply:

```
$("li")
    .find("a[title='yourTitle']")
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .remove();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/UrGcm/).

But this only works if there is a single `a` tag where the title attribute is `yourTitle` (or whatever title you decide to look for).

Comment: Ya it works, but if there are no elements which matched the title than the result shows the entire list

Comment: Just add an `else` to the `if` that removes all the `li` elements.